# Stretch an image (in a specific ratio) in such a way that number of pixels of the image remains unchanged?

Tags: images, pixel

I have an image to be displayed on an LCD screen, but my LCD screen is made of rectangular pixels and this makes my image deformed. i.e. A circle will appear as an ellipse.

In order to correct this, I need to change the image aspect ratio without changing the pixel dimensions. Is there any way to do this?

Any tool (GIMP, Photoshop, Illustrator) will be appreciated.

Comment: If the aspect is encoded to the pixels then no its not possible. If on the other hand the stretch is in the software you didn't see the original pixels anyway then yes. Mostly i would say the answer is WTF. Not because of you but because of the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is some [pixel aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio) correction.

> I need to change the image aspect ratio without changing the pixel dimensions.

Actually you do need to change the pixel dimensions. Or the pixel dimensions of the content of your image (meaning some of it will be cropped). Your image is being stretched as it is now, so the dimensions of *something* need to change.

In Photoshop you can set the view to compensate for various pixel aspect ratios. With a document open, choose **View → Pixel Aspect Ratio** and then choose a pixel aspect ratio that’s compatible with the video format that you’ll be using.

There are a number of predefined aspect ratios or you can set your own custom value. More about pixel aspect ratios in Photoshop here: [Photoshop Help / Adjust pixel aspect ratio](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-images-video.html#adjust_pixel_aspect_ratio)

Setting the the Pixel Aspect Ratio in this manner only changes the view for preview purposes—It doesn't actually affect your file in any way. What you need to do is correct your file so that it appears correct in your desired pixel aspect ratio.

You can either do this by-eye and adjust untill you are happy with the result—Or, since you know the ratio, stretch the image by that amount.

Comment: And the low-tech way to determine the aspect ratio (in lieu of documentation) is to: (assuming the image is stretched horizontally)  display the image, take a ruler and measure the vertical and horizontal axes of the deformed circle, divide the vertical by the horizontal, and then use the result to multiply the pixel width of the image.

Comment: @Yorik that's one way to do it!